# i can not puplish a text much 60 words

Tags: php

Im going bananas in this error,
when i submit form , can you help me out? thanks in advance

here's the error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's perfect. Surround Yourself with English The absolute best way to learn ' at line 1

```
<?php 
include "base.php"; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      $post_title = $_POST['title'];
      $post_date = date('y-m-d');
      $post_author = $_POST['author'];
      $post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
      $post_content = $_POST['content'];
      $post_image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $image_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


    if($post_title=='' or $post_author=='' or $post_keywords=='' or $post_content=='' or 

$post_image==''){

    echo "<script>alert('Any of the fields is empty')</script>";
    exit();
    }

    else {

     move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/$post_image");

      $insert_query = "insert into posts 

(post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_keywords,post_content)  values 

('$post_title','$post_date','$post_author','$post_image','$post_keywords','$post_content')";



    if(mysql_query($insert_query)){

    echo "<script>alert('post published successfuly')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('view_posts.php','_self')</script>";

    }

else
      {
echo mysql_error();

   }



}


}
?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: A single quote is breaking your query up. See here http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Try escaping the content that you are trying to insert. Looks like something in `$post_content` is tripping up the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are failing to properly escape the input data, so the `'` in your *data* is being treated like an SQL *special character*.

This problem also renders you  vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Stop using `mysql_` — it is [obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068). Use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) that supports [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which are the best way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with quotes.

Before building your SQL sentence, escape all the values with: `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

**BUT, please, please, please**, use `Mysqli`'s statements as a better option.

Comment: I'm kind of leaning towards PDO now rather than mysqli - it seems to cause less issues once you get into the world of calling stored procedures.

Comment: You're right @CD001 . I said `mysqli` because it is more similar to `mysql` extension, so the change is simplier. But your option is better.

Answer (score -2):

```
insert_query = "insert into posts (post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_keywords,post_content)  values 

('".$post_title."','".$post_date."','".$post_author."','".$post_image."','".$post_keywords."','".$post_content."')";
```